node editor - How to set the glow color differently from main on emission
I am trying to make a lava-like glow texture with emission. I want the main part of the object to be yellow, but the surrounding glow to be orange. However, when I use the emission with Bloom in Eevee, the object always becomes a very bright white or pale color and turning down the strength barely helps as when the color becomes more saturated, the glow is lost already.
Here is the WIP model:

Here is the node setup:


Have you tried just using red or orange instead of yellow?

Well, yes, but the problem still remains - the color of the object itself is highly desaturated. And, as stated, I wanted the color of the main object to be yellow while the glow to be orange.
